# MySQL REGEXP to find a word

Tags: mysql, regex

I am using the twitter API to fill my database with tweets. I now want to be able to search for words in the tweets. I have realized that this is not as simple as using LIKE because LIKE will do the following:

> If searching for 'pan' like would return tweets that have words that contain that string
>     such as 'companion'.

I have decided I need to use regular expressions to solve this. Basically I want to be able to find only full words (not if they are contained in other words like the above) in the tweets I am searching. So how would I be able to do this?

The following is what I have so far:

```
SELECT tweet_id, text FROM tweets WHERE text REGEXP ''
```

I am just unsure about what the regular expression should contain.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `[[:<:]]` and `[[:>:]]` as word boundaries that match the beginning and end of words, respectively: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html

```
SELECT tweet_id, text FROM tweets WHERE text REGEXP '[[:<:]]pan[[:>:]]'
```

Comment: I wasn't actually aware of the word boundaries regex within MySQL - that does work more nicely than my own answer.

Comment: Thank you! And for the source also.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ you can enter in some test data and play around with your regex strings until you get one that works just right.

As a starting point, you probably want something like `'.* pan .*'`

`.` = a wildcard character
`.*` = matches 1 or more of the wildcard character

This will work for *most* examples of your search but you will need to play with regexr to get one that works for all possibilities